# Connect to a shared drive in java

Tags: java, windows, io

I need to connect to a windows shared drive so I can make a directory and then some files in that directory. I am not sure how I would go about this. Can you use any built in classes for java?

Answer (score 0):

If you map the drive onto your machine you should be able to access the drive with the normal filepath "(Drive Letter):/"

Depending on your network configuration you might also be able to use the filepath "\(Server name)\"

Comment: Do you put the server name in ()

Comment: No, and for some reason the text back is removing my double back slash. It would be \\server\filepath